# Which iOS classes that don't support zeroing weak references?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a list of classes in iOS that can't be referred with a `__weak` pointer when using automatic reference counting (ARC)?

Apple's [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) only lists Mac classes so far:

> **Which classes don’t support zeroing-weak references?**
>
> You cannot currently create zeroing-weak references to instances of the following classes:
>
> `NSATSTypesetter`, `NSColorSpace`, `NSFont`, `NSFontManager`, `NSFontPanel`, `NSImage`, `NSMenuView`, `NSParagraphStyle`, `NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter`, `NSTableCellView`, `NSTextView`, `NSViewController`, `NSWindow`, and `NSWindowController`. In addition, in OS X no classes in the AV Foundation framework support weak references.

Is there a similar list for UIKit classes or even iOS-specific classes in general?

Thanks.

Comment: Starting in 10.8, instances of NSWindow, NSWindowController, and NSViewController can be pointed to by ARC weak references: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_8SharingService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to form a weak reference to an object that doesn't support weak references, the program should die immediately.  This is mentioned in the *Objective-C Advancements in Depth* video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  So you should know immediately if you find a class that doesn't support them.

I'm pretty sure the lack of mention in *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes* means that all `UIKit` classes are safe.  I'm not sure if the warning about `AV Foundation` classes applies to iOS or not.  I tested creating a weak reference to `AVCaptureSession` on both iOS 5 and Lion and neither crashed.  I tested creating a weak reference to an `NSWindow` on Lion and it crashed with the message `cannot form weak reference to instance (0x102232ef0) of class NSWindow`.

Comment: No, the program didn't die _immediately_ (as in on startup) - only dies when the reference is made. Also as mentioned, at least `UITableViewCell`-descendants are not compatible, tested in iOS 5 iPad Simulator.

Comment: @adib please include in your question the actual error message you get when trying to create a weak reference to a table cell.

Comment: `UITableViewCell` allows weak references.  I have tested it.  If you got an exception, post the console messages and the stack trace.

Comment: Also, I don't know why you think “immediately” means “at start-up”.  If I said “If you press the print button, the program should display the print dialog box immediately”, would you think that means the program displays the print dialog box at startup?

Comment: @robmayoff You're right, it must have been something else that caused the error.