# Weak IBOutlet property and ARC issue

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, iboutlet

my code:

```
@interface WBMessageTableCellView : NSTableCellView

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *authName;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *createdTime;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *userProfileImageView;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextView *statusTextView;

@end
```

but I got this error, 
[image]
what's wrong with this? I have to change my code to this, and it works,

```
@interface WBMessageTableCellView : NSTableCellView
{
    IBOutlet NSTextView *statusTextView;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *authName;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *createdTime;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *userProfileImageView;

@property NSTextView *statusTextView;
```

I have arc turned on on this file, and the project is newly created. not converted from non-arc project.

Comment: Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146540/which-ios-classes-that-dont-support-zeroing-weak-references You can't create weak references to classes which don't support weak references to their instances. If this answers your question I will promote this comment to an answer.

Comment: so it's just because Apple haven't complete the task?

Comment: Well, impossible for me to tell. I'm sure they had a reason not to suport weak references to NSTextView instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've promoted my comment to an answer:

> Please take a look at this question:
>   [Which iOS classes that don't support zeroing weak references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146540/which-ios-classes-that-dont-support-zeroing-weak-references)
>   You can't create weak references to classes which don't support weak
>   references to their instances.